# Rails 5.0.0.1 won't install due to dependency issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, railstutorial.org

I've been trying to install Ruby on Rails on my Ubuntu 16.04 installation, however when I run `gem install rails -v 5.0.0.1`, I get the following error:

```
michael@michael-laptop:~/Programming/Ruby/RailsTutorial$ gem install rails -v 5.0.0.1
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyResolutionError)
    conflicting dependencies rack (~> 1.0) and rack (~> 2.0)
  Activated rack-2.0.1 via:
    rack-2.0.1 (~> 2.0), actionpack-5.0.0.1 (= 5.0.0.1), rails-5.0.0.1 (= 5.0.0.1)
  instead of (~> 1.0) via:
    sprockets-2.8.0 (~> 2.8), sprockets-rails-2.1.4 (>= 2.0.0), rails-5.0.0.1 (= 5.0.0.1)
```

I'm trying to do this as part of the Rails tutorial. Does anyone know how this issue might be able to be fixed?

Comment: What is your ruby version?

Comment: ruby -v gives `ruby 2.1.2p95`, but I also have ruby2.3 installed.

Comment: Rails 5 requires rack 2.x, which in turn requires ruby >= 2.2.2

Comment: This may be helpful: https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1653

Answer (score 0):

Update your Ruby version first, then install rails. I always use [this](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/16.04) article for installing up-to-date ruby and rails enviroments